# jquery close on click outside

Tags: jquery, html, click

i have made a side navigation menu which slides from left to right on the click of a button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav-toggle").click(function(){
    $("#page").toggleClass("margin");
  });
});
```

when the '#nav-toggle' button is clicked the '#page' margin increases from 0px to 600px.

```
    .margin {
margin-left:600px;width:380px;overflow-x:hidden
}


<div id="side-menu">

<nav>
    <a class="nav-links" href="#home">home</a>
    <a class="nav-links" href="#about">about</a>
    <a class="nav-links" href="#contact">contact</a>
</nav><!-- end of nav  -->
```

how would i close the menu by clicking outside of it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$('body').on('click',function(event){
   if(!$(event.target).is('#nav-toggle')){
     $("#page").removeClass("margin");
   }
});
```

Comment: it also opens the menu if i click anywhere on the page. how would i change that?

Comment: also what i did was change 'body' to '#page' because when i clicked on the nav it also closed it.

Comment: I used HTML in place of BODY because body height is based off content height.

Answer (score 0):

Easy ... use delegates explained here: 
http://api.jquery.com/on/  "Check **Direct and delegated events**"

basically what i say is ... when the user clicks anywhere on the document and the source is not inside the #side-menu **:not(#side-menu)** remove the class margin from the #nav-toggle

```
$(document).on({
   click: function(){
      $("#nav-toggle").removeClass("margin")
   }
},":not(#side-menu)");
```